# Type mismatch: inferred type is Query? but CollectionReference? was expected

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
var query = firebase.firestoreDb?.collection("myData")
    ?.document("myBooks")
    ?.collection("science")

if (sampleQns != ""){
    query = query?.whereEqualTo("sampleQns", "yes")
}
if (diagram != ""){
    query?.whereEqualTo("diagram", "yes")
}

query?.get()
```

I get type mismatch error(inferred type is Query? but CollectionReference? was expected) if I code like this...

Comment: try `var query : Query =`

Comment: It works when I define it as Query..! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following variable:

```
var query = firebase.firestoreDb?.collection("myData")
    ?.document("myBooks")
    ?.collection("science")
```

Is of type [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) which extends [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) class. There is no way in Kotlin in which you can save an object of type Query into an object of type CollectionReference, hence that type mismatch.

However, you can save an object of type CollectionReference into a variable Query, and this is because a CollectionReference is actually a Query without filters.

As also @PeterHaddad mentioned in his comment, you should explicitly define the `query` to be of type Firestore Query:

```
var query: Query = firebase.firestoreDb?.collection("myData")
    ?.document("myBooks")
    ?.collection("science")
```